# Angular Javascript find method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, find

Here's my code:

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyCtrl]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.names = [
        {
            "name": "AAAAAA",
            "down": "False"
        },
        {
            "name": "BBBBBB",
            "down": "45%"
        },
        {
            "name": "CCCCC",
            "down": "12%"
        }
        ];

    $scope.datas = [
        {
            "data": "AAAAAA/45%"
        }
        ];

    $scope.getTheRightData = data => $scope.datas.map(d=>d.data.split('/')[0]).find(d=>d===data);
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
            <td>{{name.down}}</td>
            <td ng-bind="getTheRightData(name.name)"></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
  </table>
```

What i do : one element from `$scope.datas` will match an element in `$scope.names`, but it only shows when `name.name` is the same. I need when `name.name` and `name.down` is the same, something like this : `<td ng-bind="getTheRightData(name.name,name.down)"></td>`, and in controller

```
$scope.getTheRightData = data => $scope.datas.map(d=>d.data.split('/')[0][1]).find(d=>d===data);
}
```

, but it dont work.
Thanks for answers and ideas for advance!

Comment: Given the two arrays are you expecting only the first element to show on load or are you expecting that the 3rd `td` is only populated when it has a match?

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample answer check the below code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyCtrl]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';

  $scope.names = [{
    "name": "AAAAAA",
    "down": "False"
  }, {
    "name": "BBBBBB",
    "down": "45%"
  }, {
    "name": "CCCCC",
    "down": "12%"
  }, {
    "name": "AAAAAA",
    "down": "45%"
  }];

  $scope.datas = [{
    "data": "AAAAAA/45%"
  }, {
    "data": "CCCCC/12%"
  }];

  $scope.getTheRightData = data => $scope.datas.map(param => {
    return {
      name: param.data.split('/')[0],
      down: param.data.split('/')[1]
    }
  }).find(param => param.name == data.name && param.down == data.down);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
          <td>{{name.name}}</td>
          <td>{{name.down}}</td>
          <td>{{getTheRightData(name)}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```